# Reflect (MethodByName) not valid

Tags: go

Problem at reflection, with MethodByName

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)

type test struct {}

var serviceType = map[string]reflect.Value{
    "test": reflect.ValueOf(test{}),
}

func (t *test) prnt()  {
    fmt.Println("test ok")
}

func callFunc(strct string, fName string)  {

    s := serviceType[strct].MethodByName(fName)
    if !s.IsValid(){
        fmt.Println("not correct")
        return
    }

    s.Call(make([]reflect.Value,0))
}

func main()  {
    callFunc("test", "prnt")
}
```

Output:

```
not correct
```

Playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/ZLEQBGYoUOB

Could you help, what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things needs to be corrected.

1. MethodByName() returns only Exported methods. So you have to rename `prnt` tp `Prnt`
2. Needs to pass a pointer of struct `test` to `reflect.ValueOf()` method.

Here is the modified working code https://play.golang.org/p/4MK2kqOz6e2

Comment: Thank you so much!